# How to run/debug serverless(framework) application locally?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, serverless, serverless-framework

I have this application created with serverless framework using python language, but I am not finding a way to debug it locally or at least run it just to test it out before deploying it to amazon's web services.

Is there any way to run serverless application (with python) using pycharm or any other tool?

Comment: which serverless framework did you used? your question is not clear.
You have used the [serverless](https://www.serverless.com/)? If yes, you're in complete wrong way, this "framework" is used for publish your infrastructure like Terraform, puppet and others.

Comment: @LucasPaim yes that is the framework, I used it to generate the yaml file and have it ready for deploy, but I am not finding a way to run or debug locally as it will speed up my process. Sorry if the questions are kind of 'noob' but I am new to serverless development in general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is possible to some extent. The first way is using `invoke local` command to invoke individual functions. The other way is to use `serverless-offline` plugin: https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline

Answer (score 0):

Running Lambda locally. First, you need to be able to run Lambda locally. ...
Enable PyCharm to run bash scripts. Now we want to run python-lambda-local from PyCharm rather than the terminal. ...
Create a bash script. ...
Edit Run Configurations in PyCharm. ...
Enjoy!